# Why cant call ActionResult for uploading process?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, model-view-intent

Here is my project in `MVI` that has `UseCase`. I can call `Successful` and `Error` in `UploadImageResult` sealed class. But when want to show progress in UI, should call `UploadedProgressBarProcess` and then get this in `ViewModel`. That's not call and work this. Why can't do this?

```
class UploadImageUseCase(
        private val documentsRepository: DocumentsRepository,
        private val context: Context
    ) : UseCase<UploadImageAction, UploadImageResult> {
    
        override fun apply(upstream: Observable<UploadImageAction>): ObservableSource<UploadImageResult> {
            return upstream.flatMap { action ->
                val imageToFile = FileHelper(context).getFile(action.uri[action.uploadingRequestCount - 1])
                val requestFile = imageToFile.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                val body = ProgressbarUploadingProcessHelper(requestFile.contentType(), imageToFile)
                { percentageOfProgress ->
                    UploadImageResult.UploadedProgressBarProcess(
                        percentageOfProgress, action.uri, action.imageId
                    )
                }
                documentsRepository.uploadImage(
                    convertFileToMultipart(action.file, action.file.name, body),
                    action.imageId,
                ).toObservable().map { result ->
                    result.fold(onSuccess = { response ->
                        UploadImageResult.Successful(
                            action.imageId, response.data?.token ?: "", action.uploadingRequestCount, action.uri
                        )
                    }, onFailure = {
                        UploadImageResult.Error(action.imageId, action.uri, action.uploadingRequestCount)
                    })
                }.startWithItem(UploadImageResult.Loading(action.imageId, action.uri, action.uploadingRequestCount))
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    data class UploadImageAction(val imageId: String, val uri: ArrayList<Uri>, val file: File, val uploadingRequestCount: Int) :
        Action
    
    sealed class UploadImageResult : ActionResult {
        data class Loading(val imageId: String, val uri: ArrayList<Uri>, val uploadingRequestCount: Int) : UploadImageResult()
        data class UploadedProgressBarProcess(
            val percentageOfProgress: Int, val uri: ArrayList<Uri>, val imageId: String
        ) :
            UploadImageResult()
    
        data class Successful(val imageId: String, val token: String, val uploadingRequestCount: Int, val uri: ArrayList<Uri>) :
            UploadImageResult()
    
        data class Error(val imageId: String, val uri: ArrayList<Uri>, val uploadingRequestCount: Int) : UploadImageResult()
    }
    
    private fun convertFileToMultipart(
        file: File, fileName: String, body: ProgressbarUploadingProcessHelper
    ): MultipartBody.Part {
        val requestFile = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fileName, body)
    }
```